# Java: Updating a .txt file as the program runs and being able to see the change

Tags: java, file, io, enterprise

I have to run a Java program that needs to keep track of transactions the user makes. I need to log these transactions in the .txt file. 
Everything is working well with my code, expect that I cannot see the .txt file - it is not created - till the programs closes.

The goal for our Project is to be able to see this file get updated live as the programs is running. The user completes Order #1 and the transactions of that order get logged into the .txt file and one can see the changes right away - while the program is still running. The user completes Order #2 and the transaction of that order are appended to the .txt file - again, while the program is running.

I am using:

```
PrintWriter out;
out = (new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt", true)));

(writes lines to file)

out.flush();
out.close();
```

This code is within a method that gets called every time the users finishes his or her order. As soon as the order is finish the log.txt file should reflect the changes right away without the program quitting. I have spend hours on searching how to do this but I have not suceeeded. I am also relatively new to Java and programming; therefore, any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably the text editor's fault, and not the program. If you reopen the file, are the contents updated?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Nothing is updated. When the log.txt file does not exist yet - it was to be created - it does not exist in the directory till the program exits. I am also using IntelliJ to run the program. log.txt only shows when the program finishes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964169/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-file-to-be-written-in-java-so-that-after-the-function

Comment: Without a decent [mcve] it will be near impossible to guess what bug your program might have. If you still are in search of a solution, consider creating and posting this.

Comment: I found the problem! Thanks @AndrewWilliamson for mentioning that. I realized that it was Intellij holding the file from showing up in the file directory. I run it another different way and I could see the file showing up, and the "Last Modified" getting updated with the time every new order was submitted! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at standard logging framework for java? ([slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/)) it's an api that is pretty much ubiquitous and there are many very good implementations, like [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), or log4j and so on. Let those worry about writing to files. Program to an interface (slf4j interface, namely) and copy-paste (if you don't want to do anything fancy) some xml configuration for the logger implementation from the internet.

you would not have to open files, or flush and close them. your code would be:

```
log.info("something happened");
```

read up on this topic, as there practically aren't serious java projects that would not have a logging element to them. invest some time into learning this framework once, as you can use it forever.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your buffer is unloaded and written onto the file only when you invoke the flush method. Buffer waits to accumulate some data before the writing operation.